# Challenging diagram with breakout labels explanation

Tags: html, css

I have some cryptic nomenclature labels for some products and I'd like to explain them using a diagram with breakout labels, something like that:

[image: Breakout diagram example]

That is, I have some sort of long and cryptic label ("A-253-QZ" in this example, in real world there are typically 8-10-12 components), and I need to explain its parts, that "A" means series designator, "253" is, for example, "max speed" and "QZ" is acceptable batteries type.

I need to generate these diagrams on the fly, so I'd prefer it to be laid out with HTML + CSS.

My best effort so far is a complex table that uses its borders to draw these breakout lines - [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ceyajo/1). It looks like that:

[image: HTML table rendering]

I understand that it's quite suboptimal:

- it uses HTML tables for formatting, that is evil
- vertical lines are properly centered, but it generates hell of a columns to do it
- horizontal lines are not aligned to center of the line, but to its bottom
- horizontal lines do not touch the end of the explanation captions

Any ideas how to do it better / without tables / fix mentioned issues? Any ideas on better representation of a concept?

Comment: Challenge Accepted. `:)`

Comment: Can you use Canvas / SVG to do this?

Comment: You can use `:after` and `:before` pseudo element.

Comment: This is something where a graphic using e.g. SVG would show its full power. Even if you use HTML here – what should it describe semantically?

Comment: Have a look at my answer buddy.

Comment: This is without the borders: http://output.jsbin.com/mosepocope/1

Comment: Don't believe that tables are evil. It's misusing tables that is evil

Comment: @PraveenKumar: You can, you, honestly, I don't see much point. Canvas rendering would look ugly on any mobile device with pinch-and-zoom browsers + it would require JavaScript to do it => problems with search engine indexing. Raw SVG lacks automatic text layouting - i.e. you can't easily make it match components width and explanation lines heights without font metrics + intricate calculations.

Comment: @feeela: In fact, it has very straightforward semantic structure - like a dictionary. A term (`QZ`) leads a definition (`batteries type`). One might fancy to structure it as a `dl`/`dt`/`dd` structure.

Comment: @GreyCat see revised answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my try. Just trying to be semantic, as few extra elements as I could

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

.container * {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 4px;
  position: relative;
}

.item:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 200px;
}


.item:before {
  content: attr(data-label);
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: calc(100% + 10px);
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
} 

.item:nth-of-type(1):before {
  bottom: -50px;
} 

.item:nth-of-type(2):before {
  bottom: -80px;
} 

.item:nth-of-type(3):before {
  bottom: -110px;
} 

.item:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 0px blue;
  background-image: linear-gradient(blue, blue), linear-gradient(blue, blue);
  background-position: 50% 0%, 0% calc(100% - 10px);
  background-size: 2px calc(100% - 10px), 50% 2px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
} 

.item:nth-of-type(1):after {
  top: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: -1;
} 

.item:nth-of-type(2):after {
  top: 30px;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: -2;
} 

.item:nth-of-type(3):after {
  top: 30px;
  height: 90px;
  z-index: -3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item" data-label="Category 1">FIRST</div>
    <p>-</p>
    <div class="item" data-label="Category 2">SEC</div>
    <p>-</p>
    <div class="item" data-label="Category 3">THIRD</div>
</div>
```

Another example, a little better, and shrink-wrapping the container.

The pseudo elements are no longer absolute positioned, so the container can adjust the size. And avoiding some calc uses, that always are harded than maintain than padding, for instance.

I still need a padding set before hand on the container, though. Can't see how to avoid this ...

```css
.container {
  border: solid 1px red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 200px;
}

.container * {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 4px;
  position: relative;

}

.item:before {
  content: attr(data-label);
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  right: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  padding-right: 8px;
} 

.item:nth-of-type(1):before {
  top: 30px;
} 

.item:nth-of-type(2):before {
  top: 55px;
} 

.item:nth-of-type(3):before {
  top: 85px;
} 

.item:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 0px blue;
  background-image: linear-gradient(blue, blue), linear-gradient(blue, blue);
  background-position: 50% 0%, 0% calc(100% - 10px);
  background-size: 2px calc(100% - 10px), 50% 2px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
} 

.item:nth-of-type(1):after {
  height: 30px;
} 

.item:nth-of-type(2):after {
  height: 60px;
} 

.item:nth-of-type(3):after {
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item" data-label="Category 1">FIRST</div>
    <p>-</p>
    <div class="item" data-label="Category 2">SEC</div>
    <p>-</p>
    <div class="item" data-label="Category 3">THIRD</div>
</div>
```

Comment: A neat and clever solution! I particularly liked the design solution and the trick with backgrounds and gradients. There's two major issues here — one has to reserve space beforehand — `height` for `.container` and `margin-left` for `item:first-of-type`). Any tips on how to automate height calculation (for example, with CSS `calc`)?

Comment: Happy that it helped ! I have added another example, and now the height is adjusted automatically

Comment: Thanks! I guess it makes it overall most complete and semantic-styled answer here. I've developed by own subversion of your code, extracting stuff in `data-label` into separate elements and having extra container element on top of them to group label + item — it makes it possible to have some complex HTML markup in labels.

Answer (score 7):

Hope this is decent! LoL. Just a try, I know this is not the optimal:

[image]

**Full Code**

```
<table class="breakout">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2" class="comp label">A</td>
    <td class="label">-</td>
    <td colspan="2" class="comp label">253</td>
    <td class="label">-</td>
    <td colspan="2" class="comp label">QZ</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" class="caption">series</td>
    <td class="ruler-hv"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="ruler-v"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="ruler-v"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="ruler-v"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="ruler-v"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" class="caption">max speed</td>
    <td class="ruler-h"></td>
    <td class="ruler-h"></td>
    <td class="ruler-h"></td>
    <td class="ruler-hv"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="ruler-v"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="ruler-v"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" class="caption">batteries type</td>
    <td class="ruler-h"></td>
    <td class="ruler-h"></td>
    <td class="ruler-h"></td>
    <td class="ruler-h"></td>
    <td class="ruler-h"></td>
    <td class="ruler-h"></td>
    <td class="ruler-hv"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Fiddle: http://output.jsbin.com/yalacoceda**

Comment: Good idea: I've tried this rowspan trick myself, but somehow failed. Looks like it works in fact. But it's still lots of hacky tables (twice more, in fact ;)) and lead lines do not touch explanations. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Ha! The crazy fishing downvotes have started to appear. Why can't coward speak up!

Comment: @GreyCat You alive? `:P`

Comment: I agree that `text-align: right` is obvious workaround.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to display the following information:

```
series: A
max-speed: 253
batteries type: QZ
```

It would be appropriate if you change your markup to [dl, dd and dt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl). The following example displays the data just the way you want but with following constraints:

- Width and height of labels is fixed
- Height of values is fixed

```css
dl, dt, dd {
  margin: 0;
}
dl {
  padding-top: 48px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
/* labels */
dt {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 96px;
  line-height: 24px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
/* values */
dd {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  font-size: 32px;
}
/* connector */
dd::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 100%;
  right: 50%;
  left: -999px;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
dd:nth-of-type(1)::after {
  height: 12px;
}
dd:nth-of-type(2)::after {
  height: 36px;
}
dd:nth-of-type(3)::after {
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>series</dt>
  <dd>A</dd>
  <dt>max-speed</dt>
  <dd>253</dd>
  <dt>batteries type</dt>
  <dd>QZ</dd>
</dl>
```

[Here is a CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaEKBq?editors=110) which uses LESS variables. You can edit the width and height variables to re-generate CSS.

Comment: Alas, minuses `-`, spaces and sometimes other characters are also significant part of the code, not something I've made up to separate groups, so it's technically incorrect to insert it automatically after every 2nd element. Also, there could be more than 3 elements (although I agree that from practical POV we can generate, say, 100 of them and that would be fine for 99.99% of real-world examples).

Comment: (i) skip the last two rules then and insert hyphens inside values (ii) generated CSS rules for _n_-cases is not unusual. For example most CSS grid systems have generated rules for, e.g. 10 or 16 columns.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jq61ffh8/2/).

Here's an implementation without using `<table>`:

```
<style type="text/css">
.tbl {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
    clear: both;
    border: #DDD solid 1px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.col {
    display: table-cell;
    border: #DDD solid 1px;
    position: relative;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.col1 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.row1 {
    font-size: 42px;
}

.border-bottom-green {
    border-bottom: green solid 1px;
}

.half-v-border {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #DDD;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.half-h-border {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #DDD;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}

.half-h-border.colored-bg,
.half-v-border.colored-bg {
    background-color: green;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.first-quarter-border {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-right: green solid 1px;
    border-bottom: green solid 1px;
}
</style>

<div class="tbl">
    <div class="row row1">
        <div class="col col1"></div>
        <div class="col col2 border-bottom-green">A</div>
        <div class="col col3"> - </div>
        <div class="col col4 border-bottom-green">253</div>
        <div class="col col5"> - </div>
        <div class="col col6 border-bottom-green">QZ</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row2">
        <div class="col col1">series</div>
        <div class="col col2">
            <div class="half-v-border"></div>
            <div class="half-h-border"></div>
            <div class="first-quarter-border"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col3">
            <div class="half-h-border"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col4">
            <div class="half-v-border colored-bg"></div>
            <div class="half-h-border"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col5">
            <div class="half-h-border"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col6">
            <div class="half-v-border colored-bg"></div>
            <div class="half-h-border"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row3">
        <div class="col col1">max speed</div>
        <div class="col col2">
            <div class="half-v-border"></div>
            <div class="half-h-border colored-bg"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col3">
            <div class="half-h-border colored-bg"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col4">
            <div class="half-v-border"></div>
            <div class="half-h-border"></div>
            <div class="first-quarter-border"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col5">
            <div class="half-h-border"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col6">
            <div class="half-v-border colored-bg"></div>
            <div class="half-h-border"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row3">
        <div class="col col1">batteries type</div>
        <div class="col col2">
            <div class="half-v-border"></div>
            <div class="half-h-border colored-bg"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col3">
            <div class="half-h-border colored-bg"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col4">
            <div class="half-v-border"></div>
            <div class="half-h-border colored-bg"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col5">
            <div class="half-h-border colored-bg"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col6">
            <div class="half-v-border"></div>
            <div class="half-h-border"></div>
            <div class="first-quarter-border"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- .tbl -->
```

Comment: It's still the `display: table`, although without using `<table>` tag directly. I guess if we're abusing tables, I'd rather do that directly rather than trying to hide it with renaming divs %)